# What is a word for two word phrases which describe the same thing but are worded differently?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm normalizing some data in a spreadsheet (because I party hard) and I have entries like

> "Windows 7 Pro 64 bit"

and

> "Win 7 x64 pro"

These entries obviously describe the same thing, and I'm changing them as such. What is the word or phrase which would describe these two different-but-identical-in-spirit entries?

Comment: They are ***equivalent***

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that'd work. I'm an IT technician, and those strings aren't equivalent. I suppose I'm looking for a word meaning "identical in spirit".

Comment: They are semantically equivalent although not identical.

Comment: "semantically equivalent" is what I think I'm looking for. Give that as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer. I'll upvote "euphemism" and "paraphrase" as well.

Comment: They are synonyms, are they not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say that they are ***synonymous***. From the *OED*:

**synonymous *adj.***

> 1. a. Having the character of a synonym; equivalent in meaning: said of words or phrases denoting the same thing or idea. ("synonymous, adj." OED Online. Oxford University Press.)

I probably wouldn't say that the various terms are actually *synonyms*, but the adjective seems to be a fairly good fit.